# SWIG - use Python variable as cpp_int

Tags: python, c++, boost, swig

Good evening,

I wrote a function in C++ that takes a cpp_int from the boost::multiprecision library as argument.
I am trying to use this function in Python using SWIG with the following header:

```
/* example.i */
%module example
%{
    #include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp>

    using namespace boost::multiprecision;
    /* Put header files here or function declarations like below */
    extern cpp_int factor(cpp_int n, int seed);
%}

extern cpp_int factor(cpp_int  n, int seed);
```

When I run this function in Python using e.g. `example.factor(4846403, 2)`, I get the error `TypeError: in method 'factor', argument 1 of type 'cpp_int'`.

My question is: how do I convert a normal python int to the cpp_int, thus being able to use it in the function?

I am looking forward to your help.

Best regards,
Jiscona

Comment: If you have a variable `v` of type cpp_int, you can use `v.convert_to<int>()`

Comment: You would probably be better off to make a function that accecpts a regular int, and then convert it to a cpp_int inside the function, that way both SWIG and python will know how to handle the value.

Comment: You could also write a `%typemap(in) boost::multiprecision::cpp_int` that converts a Python `int` to a `cpp_int`.

Comment: @MarkTolonen I'm sorry if it's a stupid question, but where should I put your line? In the module or the C++ code?

Comment: In the module, and it requires the code to do the conversion as well. You’ll need to research how to do that and ask a more specific question if you get stuck.